# Can I use read from unistd.h to read from file into a struct?

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to do two things: read from a file descriptor into a struct and then I need to read into a memory location. For the first, I am using fread. For the second I am using read from unistd.h.

Is there anyway I can do both without needing to fopen, fclose, open, close and repeating like this? Am I able to use "read" to read into a struct?

Comment: If you need two copies, have you considered using `memcpy()`?

Comment: (1) "Reading into a struct" *is* reading into a memory location. There is no functional difference. (2) Why do you think you have to use `read()` instead of continuing to use `fread()`?

Comment: And I'm not sure whether you want to read *the same* data from the file, once into a struct and once into "raw memory" (i.e., rewind in between); or whether you want to read *sequentially*, that is, byte 1..n from the file into the struct and then byte n+1..n+x into raw memory.

Answer (score 1):

After calling `fopen()`, you may get the file descriptor of a file pointer via `fileno()`, like this:

```
int fd;
fd = fileno (fp);
```

Then you may use `read` directly. Indeed, both `fopen()` and `open()` opens a file for a process, the former returns a pointer to the file while the latter returns the file descriptor. The `FILE` type is just a `struct` which has a field that records the underlying file descriptor.

In other words, on unix-like systems, `fopen()` is implemented using `open()`, so there must be a way to use both calls simultaneously.

As a note, on my system (wsl2), the definition of `FILE` can be found under the path `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types/struct_FILE.h`, which looks something like this:

```
struct _IO_FILE
{
  /* ... */
  int _fileno;
  /* ... */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can read data (here a string) into a struct:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DATA_LEN 1024

struct s {
  char data[DATA_LEN];
};

int main() {
    int fd = open("1.c", O_RDONLY);
    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("file");
        return 1;
    }
    struct s s;
    ssize_t n = read(fd, s.data, DATA_LEN);
    printf("%.*s\n", (int) n, s.data);
    close(fd);
}
```

Comment: I was using fread already, I was asking how I could do so with the read system call

Comment: @JobHunter69 I updated example to use open/read/close.

Comment: @AllanWind You misunderstood OP's question.

Comment: @Haris I am not sure, actually, but hopefully op will chime in.  It technically answers the question asked "Am I able to use "read" to read into a struct?"

Comment: @AllanWind Touche.

Comment: @JobHunter69 Consider accepting the answer that helped you best.

Answer (score 0):

> Re: Is there anyway I can do both without needing to fopen, fclose,
> open, close and repeating like this?

Yes. You can obtain a file descriptor corresponding to the `FILE *` with `fileno()`. From the man page:

> The function fileno() examines the argument stream and returns
> the integer file descriptor used to implement this stream.  The
> file descriptor is still owned by stream and will be closed when
> fclose(3) is called.

As an example:

```
/** 
*   @brief  Opens the file whose name is the string pointed to 
*           by file_name and associates a stream with it.
*   @return A file descriptor corresponding to the stream on success, 
*           -1 elsewise.
*/
static int open_sesame (FILE *stream, const char *file_name) 
{
    stream = fopen (file_name, "r");
    if (!stream) {
        perror ("fopen()");
        /* Handle error here */
        return -1;
    }
    /* On failure, -1 is returned and errno is set to indicate
    *  the error. 
    */
    int fd = fileno (stream);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror ("fileno()");
        /* Handle error here */
        return -1;
    }
    return fd;
}
```

This too will do:

```
/* read() will return -1 and set errno to EBADF¹ 
*  if fileno() fails.
*/
if (read (fileno (fp), ..., ..., ...) == -1) {
    perror ("read()");
    /* Handle error here */
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to open a stream for a corresponding file descriptor, then there's `fdopen()`. From the man page:

> The fdopen() function shall associate a stream with a file
> descriptor.

A sample call:

```
/* Upon successful completion, fdopen() shall return 
*  a pointer to a stream; otherwise, a null pointer 
*  shall be returned and errno set to indicate the 
*  error.
*/
FILE *stream = fdopen (fd, "r");
if (!stream) {
    perror ("fdopen()");
    /* Handle error here */
}
```

Alternatively, as @Fe203 suggested, if you require two copies of the data, you can use the standard `memcpy()` instead of reading from the file twice. Or as you're already using POSIX system calls, it might be more efficient to map the file into memory with `mmap()` and work with it.

[1] — `EBADF`: `fd` is not a valid file descriptor or is not open for reading.